# PHP fwrite in hexidecimal format, not hexidecimal string - Over The Air firmware send

Tags: php, sockets, hex

I'm attempting to send firmware to a device over the air.
On some of my other devices, I've been successful by using fseek in the following way:

```
$handle = fopen($uniquedetails['send_firmware'], "r");
fseek($handle, $uniquedetails['ota_bytes']);
// Read the file up to the max bytes limit
$data = bin2hex(fread ($handle , $sendbytes ));
```

I'm then able to just write the data in that format to the socket and the device is happy.

```
fwrite($sock, hex2bin($hextosend));
```

Essentially, I'm reading chunks of a firmware file and sending it to the device along with the offset (ota_bytes) so the device can piece it together.

The data format for this device is the following:
992, <OTA packet address offset (4 bytes)><OTA packet length (2 bytes)>

```
$cmd = '992'; //Send OTA Data
$header = '$$';
$offset = str_pad(dechex($uniquedetails['ota_bytes']), 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
$data = "," . $input_array[1] . "," . $cmd . "," . $offset . $datalength . $data;
$length = strlen($data);
// Calculate random package flag
$flag = randLetter();
// Build packet for checksum
$data = $header . $flag . $length . $data;
$checksum = calcCheckSum($data);
// Build packet for sending
$data = $data . $checksum . "\r\n";
fwrite($sock, $data);
```

The device does not like this.
It recognises that this is an OTA packet, but errors out.

```
== GPRS Receive: 301
$$R289,861157040009546,992,0000000000808a664a7a0b2ed05849e0d22aa9d6b8701530a27a7dae50d8d1f0623a126232d43acada6a7a0a1aaaba4a5aeac97ea0a805e81aa2ba4a5aeacd86e82051b86a72316e10989be4766e5d7afc5487b022fae9e64880f3fc4ef6677b362e1d3abc144770e2ba2bcfaab271ae50d8db24b6ae9dba3c94c7a6aab271ae50d8db24b6aeE0



== OTA_RxIndex: 808464432
0
== OTA_RxDataLen: 12336
== OTA_RxData Err
```

When I contact the manufacturer, their reply was that I need to send the OTA data in hex format, not hex string (which I guess it what bin2hex is doing). Is this possible with PHP?

Comment: `their reply was that I need to send the OTA data in hex format, not hex string` this sentence makes no sense. Hex format and hex string are the same.

Comment: There is a language barrier, so it hasn't been easy. I've since found out that using hex2bin for the right parts of the message works.

Answer (score 0):

The supplier gave me an example of an acceptable packet where I noticed that their offset and length values were also in hex format:

```
$$Q556,861157040009546,992,00H 00H 00H 00H 00H 80H 8aH 66H 4aH 7aH 0bH 2eH d0H 58H
```

I changed my code to convert these back to binary.

```
$data = hex2bin($offset . $datalength . $data);
```

Then I put the rest of the packet together for sending.

```
$data = "," . $input_array[1] . "," . $cmd . "," . $data;
$length = strlen($data);
// Calculate random package flag
$flag = randLetter();
// Build packet for checksum
$data = $header . $flag . $length . $data;
$checksum = meitrackCheckSum($data);
// Build packet for sending
$data = $data . $checksum . "\r\n";
fwrite($sock, $data);
```

The device seems to accept this.